# Can we write a script to do something when a dialup connection is made to my computer?

Tags: windows, vbscript, shell, dial-up

This is the situation, I have configured a dial up server and i want to play a sound or pop up
message when a daipup connection is made to my computer from a specific location.
and it could be done with configuration file or some script to run some exe.please give me some ideas

Comment: dial-up? wow, are you from the past? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787690%28WS.10%29.aspx seems to be the Microsoft doc about it, but it's fairly tech and not that useful - although it mentions some tools you can use with it.

You can also check out the DotRas project on CodePlex.com, it has access to the entire Dial Up API, in C#...

http://www.codeplex.com/DotRas

Or take a look at

[How do I work with dial-up (RAS) connections in Windows using C#/.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722805/how-do-i-work-with-dial-up-ras-connections-in-windows-using-c-net)

for some code examples for a starting point in using the associated libraries.