# RAS event capturing

Tags: c#, .net, windows, ras

Is there a way to capture RAS events such as connection and disconnection. I need to do it on my application but it does not control the dialing process or disconnection, that's why "capture" part. My goal is to receive notification of when a connection and disconnection event happens, I've tried by listening system events but maybe i need to change something on group policy to audit RAS events or some....

PS: i would like also to capture ras dial in interface events (remote access server events) (client connection and disconnection)

Comment: Did you find something you can use in WMI?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722805/how-do-i-work-with-dial-up-ras-connections-in-windows-using-c-net

Comment: i havent tried a nothing with wmi

Comment: vulkanino, my app does not neither initialize nor close the connection, i just want to capture the event when other app do it, like mdaemon for example.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 0):

There is a component as part of the DotRas SDK which handles event based notifications from Windows upon connection and disconnection of RAS connections. Keep in mind that the events may not be immediate, it depends entirely upon when Windows notifies the component that the connection has connected or disconnected.

```
using DotRas;

RasConnectionWatcher watcher = new RasConnectionWatcher();
watcher.Connected += (sender, e) => { // Do something useful. };
watcher.Disconnected += (sender, e) => { // Do something useful. };
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

For a download link to the above mentioned SDK, see the official website at: http://dotras.codeplex.com

Hope that helps!